# How to insert an actual NULL value into a nullable column?

Tags: php, mysql, null

```
function save($gmt, $name, $address, $phone, $remark)
{
    $query= "INSERT INTO `user` (`gmt`, `name`, `address`, `phone`, `remark`) VALUES ('$gmt', '$name', '$address', '$phone', '$remark')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Here, address, phone, and remark can be `NULL`. I need it to save `NULL` whenever the variable is set to `NULL` and the column is nullable, instead of inserting an empty string.

How can I insert `NULL` value into the database using PHP?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: good read http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls562.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is PHP solution, but you have to use mysqli because mysql deprecated, please read  more about [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).
Also, you must consider [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
function save($gmt, $name, $address, $phone, $remark)
{
  if(empty($phone)){
   $phone = 'NULL';
  }else{
   $phone = "'".$phone."'";
  }
  if(empty($remark)){
   $remark = 'NULL';
  }else{
   $remark = "'".$remark."'";
  }
    $query= "INSERT INTO `user` (`gmt`, `name`, `address`, `phone`, `remark`) VALUES ('$gmt', '$name', '$address', $phone, $remark)";
    mysql_query($query);
}
//tests
save("a", "b", "c", "", "")."<br>";
save("a", "b", "c", "d", "")."<br>";
save("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")."<br>";
/*
INSERT INTO `user` (`gmt`, `name`, `address`, `phone`, `remark`) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO `user` (`gmt`, `name`, `address`, `phone`, `remark`) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', NULL)
INSERT INTO `user` (`gmt`, `name`, `address`, `phone`, `remark`) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
*/
?>
```

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2az-nv1)

Comment: Using ternary: `$phone = ($phone == '' ? NULL : $phone);` would be a lot less code.

Comment: What about if `$phone` is a string value?

Answer (score 5):

Try switching to prepared statements (which as a bonus is less prone to SQL injections).

```
function save($gmt, $name, $address, $phone, $remark)
{
    if(!isset($phone) || empty($phone)) { $phone = null; }
    if(!isset($remark) || empty($remark) { $remark = null; }

    $db = new PDO(...);

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (`gmt`, `name`, `address`, `phone`, `remark`) VALUES (:gmt, :name, :address, :phone, :remark)");
    $stmt->bindValue("gmt", $gmt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue("name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue("address", $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue("phone", $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue("remark", $remark, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

This will handle the `null` values correctly in MySQL

Comment: this might look mighty complex for him... could you post a solution using just `mysqli_`?

Comment: I don't see it being easier with `mysqli_*`.

Comment: I guess it is just the bias I have. Being very comfortable using `mysql_*` it is easier for my to migrate my projects to `mysqli_*`. That's why I think it's easier for a new use to grasp `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't print NULL - it is just an empty string. So in your example you will try to insert `''`, which in SQL again is an empty string.

You have to use `NULL` (without quotes).

And the best practice to achieve that is to use an ORM or a PHP framework with a database abstraction layer which does this for you.

Comment: But, then I would think he needs to check if the variable is empty... he can't just substitute variables in his query for `NULL`

Comment: He has to use not the deprecated functions (prefereably through a wrapper), escape the values, and put the quotes only when there's actual value... so yes, a lot of stuff to do.

Comment: Assume he is a beginner... for example look at Gerald's answer, makes a lot of sense but still complex for anybody not using OOP

Answer (score 2):

Using ternary operator, you can also use this

```
$add = ($address == '' ? NULL : $address);
$phn = ($phone == '' ? NULL : $phone);
$rmk = ($remark == '' ? NULL : $remark);
```

Answer (score -1):

fields can be NULL

-> qtd_aulas_previstas

-> qtd_aulas_dadas

```
$qtd_aulas_previstas = ( empty($qtd_aulas_previstas) ? 'NULL' : "'".$qtd_aulas_previstas."'");
$qtd_aulas_dadas     = ( empty($qtd_aulas_dadas)     ? 'NULL' : "'".$qtd_aulas_dadas."'");


//insere os dados na tabela
$inserir_tb = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO tb_turma_bimestre VALUES('', '$cod_turma', '$cod_bimestre', $qtd_aulas_previstas, $qtd_aulas_dadas, '$data_abertura', '$data_encerramento', '$date_time', '$nome_login')")or die("Error2: " .mysqli_error($conexao));
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: Thanks!  @Dharman , I will be use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` instead of `die`